# Is user_pseudo_id the same as a a session id? How to group all events by session? - Firebase BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I have an iOS App. I am trying to figure out how users move through my app. I am looking for a way to group all the events by some sort of session id. I assumed all fireBase events would have a session id. This does not seem to be the case.

I noticed there is a `user_pseudo_id`. I did some testing, where I logged an event that only I could ever have created. I noticed that sometimes the `user_pseudo_id` changes. Any idea what triggers a new id? I restarted and deleted/reinstalled the app many times so its not so easy to reverse engineer when `user_pseudo_id` changes

Thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 33):

No, `user_pseudo_id` is not a session ID. It´s a unique ID "by app install". So as long as a user uses the same app instance ("Installation") without reinstalling it, the `user_pseudo_id` stays the same. It also doesn't change on app update. But it will change if you uninstall and reinstall the app.

Comment: Can you quote an official source please? I have found this: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en but I would like for them to specify when exactly it changes

Comment: @josue.0 see https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid