# How Firebase Analytics calculates (unique) Users

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Since I noticed a **misalignment between the count of Users and the count of User IDs** on Google Analytics (for mobile apps), I need to understand technically how Google counts `Users` in mobile apps. While I have extremely clear that on Web Users are counted based on cookies, on mobile app I still have doubts (I never developed a mobile app). I made some research and I'd like to have a confirmation from people who knows it.

- I start with this assumption: the metric `Users` in Firebase / Google Analytics represents the count of the field `user_pseudo_id` ([StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53812312/6465600)). A comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58134532/6465600) seems to confirm this assumption, as well as this sentence in the [official documentation to set the User ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/userid): *"Setting a user ID is never required for Analytics to work correctly. If you're only interested in finding events belonging to the same user for the same app on a single device, you can use the user_pseudo_id. This value is generated automatically by Analytics and is stored within BigQuery for each event."*
- `user_pseudo_id` should correspond to the `App Instance ID` ([BigQuery Export Schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en)). If it's correct, *why on the documentation the App Instance ID is referenced as an example? The field allows customizations?*
- The `App Instance ID` can change in some cases (device factory reset, app uninstall, data cleared, etc. --> [`Instance ID API`](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference)), and that would explain the misalignment.

Since, as mentioned before, I have zero experience in mobile app development, can someone confirm this flow? Is everything correct or am I missing something?

Thanks!